# File IO using polymorphic datatypes in Fortran

Tags: oop, polymorphism, fortran, fortran2003

I am writing a library for importing geometries of many types (spheres,planes,NURBS surfaces, stl files...) into a scientific Fortran code. This kind of problem seems taylor-made for OOP because it is simple to define a `type :: geom` and then `type,extends(geom) :: analytic` and so on. The part I am having trouble with is the file IO.

My solution at this point is to write the parameters defining the shapes, including some flags which tell me which shape it is. When reading, I instantiate a `class(geom) :: object`, (since I don't know ahead of time which subtype it will be) but how can I read it?

I can't access any of the specific components of the subtype. I read that downcasting is *verboten*, and besides, the new `allocate(subtype :: class)` doesn't seem to work. The new `READ(FORMATTED)` doesn't seem to be implemented by ifort or gfortran. i.e.

```
module geom_mod
  type :: geom
  end type
  type,extends(geom) :: sphere
    integer :: type
    real(8) :: center(3),radius
   contains
    generic :: READ(FORMATTED)=> read_sphere ! not implemented anywhere
  end type
contains
  subroutine read_geom(object)
    class(geom),intent(out),pointer :: object     
    integer :: type

    read(10,*) object%type   ! can't access the subtype data yet

    read(10,*) type
    backspace(10)
    if(type==1) then
      allocate(sphere :: object)! downcast?
      read(10,*) object         ! doesn't work
    end if 

  end read_geom
end module
```

Am I going about this all wrong? I could hack this using something other than polymorphism, but this seems cleaner everywhere else. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: sample program using IanH's module

```
program test
  use geom_mod
  implicit none
  class(geom),allocatable :: object

  open(10)
  write(10,*) '1'
  write(10,*) sphere(center=0,radius=1)
  rewind(10)

  call read(object) ! works !
end program test
```

Comment: Your input file needs to have (at least) two records for my example code - the first record with the integer for the type, the second with the sphere data.  Do you actually get a segfault or is it an end-of-file condition?

Comment: I added a `integer :: type=1` line in the sphere type, which just confused the issue. I have no idea why this results in a seg fault, but when I stick with your module as is, it works. Thanks!

Comment: it seems as though the seg fault is linked to having any variables in the derived type with default values. So if I set `radius=1` in the type definition I get the seg fault.

Comment: Are you using Intel Fortran 12.x?  If so, this sounds like the issue with INTENT(OUT) polymorphic arguments that I alluded to.  Arguments with default initialisation or allocatable components essentially always need to be INOUT.  13.0 may fix, given early release notes.

Comment: I am using ifort -v 12.1. I can see how the default values are data going in, so the intent should be INOUT. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current gfortran and ifort do not implement defined input/output.  I have not seen any evidence that this situation will change in the near future.  However, apart from allowing some syntactic shortcuts that feature does not actually save you much work here.

One approach for this situation is to call a "factory" for extensions of geom that uses the data in the file to allocate the argument to the correct type, then hand off to a type bound procedure that reads in the type specific data.  For example:

```
module geom_mod
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
  type, abstract :: geom
  contains
    procedure(read_geom), deferred :: read
  end type geom

  abstract interface
    subroutine read_geom(object)
      import :: geom
      implicit none
      class(geom), intent(out) :: object
    end subroutine read_geom
  end interface

  type, extends(geom) :: sphere
    real(dp) :: center(3), radius
  contains
   procedure :: read => read_sphere
  end type sphere
contains
  subroutine read(object)
    class(geom), intent(out), allocatable :: object
    integer :: type
    read (10, *) type
    ! Create (and set the dynamic type of object) based on type.
    select case (type)
    case (1)     ; allocate(sphere :: object)
    case default ; stop 'Unsupported type index'
    end select
    call object%read
  end subroutine read

  subroutine read_sphere(object)
    class(sphere), intent(out) :: object
    read (10, *) object%center, object%radius
  end subroutine read_sphere
end module geom_mod
```

Current ifort (12.1.5) has issues with intent(out) polymorphic arguments that may require workarounds, but the general approach remains the same.

(Note that the subroutine read is not a type bound subroutine - to read a generic geom object use ''call read(object)'' in the conventional subroutine reference style.)